# Taking photo with custom camera Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avcapturesession

in Swift 2.3 I used this code to take a picture in custom camera:

```
 func didPressTakePhoto(){

        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {

            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                if sampleBuffer != nil {
                    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                    let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
                    let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)


                    self.captureImageView.image = image
                }
            })

    }
}
```

But his line:              `stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in`

Shows this error:

> Value of type 'AVCapturePhotoOutput' has no member
>   'captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection'

I tried solving my problem but I always get more and more errors so that is why I post my original code.

Does anybody know how to make my code work again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Sharpkits I found my solution (This code works for me):

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
            let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {

            let imageData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: nil)
            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)

            let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.absoluteColorimetric)


            let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

            let cropedImage = self.cropToSquare(image: image)

            let newImage = self.scaleImageWith(cropedImage, and: CGSize(width: 600, height: 600))

            print(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)


            self.tempImageView.image = newImage
            self.tempImageView.isHidden = false


        } else {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `AVCapturePhotoOutput`like this in Swift 3:

You need the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` which returns the  `CMSampleBuffer`.

You can get as well a preview image if you tell the `AVCapturePhotoSettings` the previewFormat

```
class CameraCaptureOutput: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    let cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    func capturePhoto() {

      let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
            let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
            let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                                 kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
                                 kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160,
                                 ]
            settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
            self.cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

    }
    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: NSError?) {

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
          print(image: UIImage(data: dataImage).size)
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot :)

Comment: I am using Swift 3 and on the `print(image: UIIMage...)` line, I get an error `Argument labels (image:) do not match any available overloads.`

Answer (score 2):

Great code. Thanks a ton for the help and examples.

Just to clarify for those of slower mental faculties like myself, the capture(_ ...etc) method is called behind the scenes when you call self.cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self) inside of your takePhoto **(or whatever you name it)** method.
You will never actually call the capture method yourself directly. It happens automatically.