# XCode 8.2.1 - Repeated warning during compilation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deprecation-warning

Here is a deal, I've got class for capturing images from iphone's camera and it uses AVCaptureStillImageOutput class. But minimal supporting version of app is iOS 10, so this class marked as deprecated. I have no time to rewrite this now, but this warning brokes building in some way. As I mentioned, it repeated about 200+ times per build and this is always error in one line - property declaration. I have been trying to disable this warning for a while, but still have no success. 
Rely on you!

Comment: Hello, I have also had problem with AVCaptureStillImageOutput, sou you can see my question and copy or just look at the answers, because they might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058320/taking-photo-with-custom-camera-swift-3

Comment: Thanks for advice! Unfortunately, I have no time to replace with new AVCapturePhotoOutput class for now. And current implementation even with deprecated method works in app, it just broke normal compilation process somehow :(

Answer (score 0):

Still do not know reason, maybe it's xcode bug. But fixed this by adding -Wno-deprecated-declarations flag to compiler options in settings manually. Default build settings and warning section in this case helpless.