# Swift 3 - Custom camera view - display still image of photo taken after button click

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.

I have a custom camera view which displays the video feed fine and a button that I want to act as a shutter.  When the user taps on the button, I want a picture taken and it to be displayed on the screen.  (e.g. like a Snapchat or Facebook Messenger style camera behavior)

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CameraVC: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

   // this is where the camera feed from the phone is going to be displayed
    @IBOutlet var cameraView : UIView!

    var shutterButton : UIButton = UIButton.init(type: .custom)

    // manages capture activity and coordinates the flow of data from input devices to capture outputs.
    var capture_session = AVCaptureSession()

    // a capture output for use in workflows related to still photography.
    var session_output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    // preview layer that we will have on our view so users can see the photo we took
    var preview_layer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    // still picture image is what we show as the picture taken, frozen on the screen
    var still_picture_image : UIImage!

    ... //more code in viewWillAppear that sets up the camera feed

    // called when the shutter button is pressed
    func shutterButtonPressed() {

        // get the actual video feed and take a photo from that feed
        session_output.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings.init(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]), delegate: self as AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate)
    }

    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

        // take the session output, get the buffer, and create an image from that buffer
        if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
            let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
            let imageData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {

            print("Here") // doesn't get here

        }

    }
```

It doesn't seem to print "Here" when running this code and I can't find any Swift 3 tutorials on how to display this image.  I'm guessing I want to take the `imageData` and assign it to my `still_picture_image` and overlay that over the camera feed somehow.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be great help.

**EDIT**

After adding the following to my code:

```
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

But I still don't get any error printed.

Comment: You could just add a UIImageView with the captured image right?

Comment: Theoretically, yes but the word "Here" is not being printed in my code so it doesn't seem to be getting past that `if` statement.

Comment: Did you call the `captureSession?.startRunning()`? hey can you post the full length code?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code into your delegate method to print out the error being thrown:

```
if let error = error {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Once you get your error resolved, I think this post should help you to extract the image: [Taking photo with custom camera Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058320/taking-photo-with-custom-camera-swift-3)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out my problem:

First, drag an UIImageView to the Storyboard and have it take up the entire screen.  This is where the still picture will be displayed after pressing the shutter button.

Create that variable in the code and link it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var stillPicture : UIImageView!
```

Then, in `viewDidLoad` make sure that you insert the `UIImageView` on top of the camera view.

```
self.view.insertSubview(stillPicture, aboveSubview: your_camera_view)
```

This is the function that is called when the shutter button is clicked:

```
func shutterButtonPressed() {

    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()

    let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
    let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                         kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
                         kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160,
                         ]
    settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
    session_output.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
}
```

Then, in your capture delegate:

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        // take the session output, get the buffer, and create an image from that buffer
        if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
            // this is the image that the user has taken!
            let takenImage : UIImage = UIImage(data: dataImage)!
            stillPicture?.image = takenImage                
        } else {
            print("Error setting up photo capture")
        }
}
```